# Optimizing merge sort for cache misses

Tags: caching, mergesort

Consider an unsorted array of N elements wherein each element is byte sized.   Let  the  size  of  the  cache  be  1  KB  with  a  cache  line  size  of  64.Further assume that the cache is organized in a fully associative manner.Compute  the  number  of  cache  misses  when  a  merge  sort  algorithm  is applied on the array.  While doing the analysis, you may want to consider different cases comparing the array size N with the cache size. Do you have any suggestions on modifying the merge sort algorithm so as to reduce the cache misses.
Assume the merge sort algorithm uses 1 temporary array to store the elements of the 2 arrays being merged.

Comment: This is a homework question. Please show your approach on this or show where you are stuck, not ask the full question right away.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that a standard bottom up merge sort could be used without modification.

There are (1024/64) = 16 cache lines. Assume the merge sort has reached a point where sorted runs are now larger than 64 bytes. During a merge operations, 2 cache lines will be used for the 2 sorted runs to be merged, and 1 cache line for the merged output. Cache misses will only occur once every 64 bytes read or written.

A bottom up merge sort will generate sorted runs with sizes of powers of 2, which might be a bit more cache friendly.

I'm not sure what is allowed in the modification to merge sort. Using a hybrid insertion sort + merge sort can reduce sort time. Let k = # elements to be sorted by insertion sort to create sorted runs of size k. A simple implementation is to determine the number of sort passes required by a basic bottom up merge sort: passcount = ceil(log2(N)). If passcount is odd, use k = 32, if passcount is even, use k = 64. This results in an even number of merge sort passes, which can alternate the direction of merge on each merge pass, to avoid having to copy data during a merge step.

> Assume the merge sort algorithm uses 1 temporary array to store the elements of the 2 arrays being merged.

This part isn't quite clear. It's more efficient to do a one time allocation of the temporary array the same size as the array to be sorted, then use identical indexing for the merge operations. A less efficient method is for every merge operation to allocate a temporary array the same size as the sum of the sizes of the two sorted runs to be merged, which would need to copy to (if before merge) or from (if after merge) the temporary array. As already mentioned, the merge operation can change the direction of merge based on bottom up merge pass or top down level of recursion to avoid copying of data.

Comment: What kind of modification might be made to reduce cache misses, if any is possible at all ?

Comment: Other than using insertion sort for runs <= 32 or 64 in size, not much. The merge operation reads data sequentially from 2 sorted runs, each of which will end up being buffered in a cache line, taking 2 of the 16 cache lines. The writes are also sequential, using 1 more of the 16 cache lines, but how writes to actual memory are buffered is processor dependent.